# inline css problem

Tags: css, inline, external

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/8mQ7x/1/

Which works fine, but as soon as I change to external css to add the background image using inline css methods, it stops working, as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/8mQ7x/

I need part of it to be inline css because the html is dynamically generated.  I am trying to create many generic icons using different images for each icon, but using a generic css external file to cause the mouse over effect.

Why does this stop working when inline css is used to add the image and how can I get this to work?

Comment: Inline css sample, works fine on my end. I am using FF 3.6

Comment: So using the inline method to add the image, does the image still change color when you mouse over it?

Comment: It does not work for me in fx4, chromium 11, or internet explorer 8.

Comment: Also, you should not use `:hover` for tags other than `<a/>` - not all browsers support `:hover` for any html tag.

Comment: It is due to precedence. CSS on the element take precedence over external css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because elements `style` CSS rule has higher priority than other CSS rules. By `background` in element style you are rewriting not only default background, but `:hover` too.

You should rewrite only `background-image`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8mQ7x/3/

Comment: I have given an example. Is that ok, or you wanted to implement something else?

Comment: Fiddle link is broken